# Micronaut keycloak

Tags: keycloak, micronaut

Dears,

Can anyone tell me which adapter to use with micronaut? i have server written on micronaut framework and keycloak up and running. For spring boot we use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

one more question: Can someone explain to me the flow how we can detect if a user already signed in using keycloak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official keycloak Micronaut adapter.

You can try the default Micronaut support oauth2 / jwt.

In this case, you will need to add these dependencies (and add their configuration properties):

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>io.micronaut.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>micronaut-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.micronaut.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>micronaut-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.micronaut.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>micronaut-security-jwt</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

A complete tutorial here: [tutorial](https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/09/21/micronaut-oauth2-and-security-with-keycloak/)

In another way, you can try this open source / community adapter [looorent](https://github.com/looorent/keycloak-micronaut-adapter) that I have never tried.

(Always you can build your own module / extension).